# Find the shortest distance from a point to curved surface

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Find the shortest distance from a point $(0,0,0)$ to curved surface $x^2+2y^2-z^2=5.$

---

What I have done is,
Let a point in the curved surface be $(a,b,c)$, and $\begin{bmatrix} {a - 0}  \\
{b - 0}\\
{c - 0}\\
\end{bmatrix}$ be vector *v*.
A vector *w* perpendicular to curved suface at (a,b,c) would be 
$ \begin{bmatrix} {2a}  \\
{4b}\\
{-2c} \\
\end{bmatrix} $.
Distance is $\frac{10}{2\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+c^2}}$ .

Then $\begin{bmatrix} {a - 0}  \\
{b - 0}\\
{c - 0}\\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} {2a}  \\
{4b}\\
{-2c} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 2a^2+4b^2-2c^2 = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\cdot 2\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+c^2}\cdot \cos{0} =10$.
and $\begin{bmatrix} {a - 0}  \\
{b - 0}\\
{c - 0}\\
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} {2a}  \\
{4b}\\
{-2c} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {-2bc-4bc}  \\
{2ac+2ac}\\
{4ab-2ab} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {-6bc}  \\
{4ac}\\
{2ab} \\
\end{bmatrix}= \sqrt{()} \cdot \sqrt{()} \cdot \sin{0}$ = *0*
 $\quad \to$ For this to be true, two of a,b, and c have to be zero.
So the answer is $\frac{10}{2\sqrt{10}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$.

Is this correct? and is there a better way?

Comment: Use partial derivatives to find the right vectors on the surface.. Now  there is a line passing thru 0 and it is parralel to one of these vectors....

Comment: I think that's what I did.

Comment: I was a bit uncarefull reading your method. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The vector $w$ is indeed orthogonal to the surface. Therefore, what you want to know is when $v$ and $w$ are collinear. That is, when is there a number $\lambda$ such that $v=\lambda w$. What this means is that you must solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a=\lambda a\\b=2\lambda b\\c=-2\lambda c\\a^2+2b^2-c^2=5.\end{array}\right.$$This system has $4$ solutions: $\pm\left(0,\sqrt{\frac52},0\right)$ and $\pm\left(\sqrt5,0,0\right)$. Therefore, the minimal distance is $\sqrt{\frac52}$.

Comment: The OP’s dot product is irrelevant, but he does set the cross product of the position vector and normal to zero, which is part of the way toward a correct solution method.

Comment: @amd You right. I missed that. But proving that two vectors are collinear proving that their cross product is $0$ looks a bit artificial to me.

Comment: Perhaps so, but using a cross product to express colinearity in this way is widely used in image processing, for example, to avoid introducing extra variables. It’s specific to $\mathbb R^3$, of course.

Comment: I see the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can set up an optimization (minimization) problem.

Let the point $(a,b,c)$ belong to the curve $x^2+2y^2-z^2=5$. The squared distance from the point to the origin is:
$$d^2(a,b,c)=(a-0)^2+(b-0)^2+(c-0)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2,$$
which needs to be minimized subject to the constraint: $a^2+2b^2-c^2=5$.
Using the Lagrange multiplier's method:
$$L(a,b,c,\lambda)=a^2+b^2+c^2+\lambda (5-a^2-2b^2-c^2)\\
\begin{cases}L_a=2a-2a\lambda =0\\
L_b=2b-4b\lambda=0 \\
L_c=2c-2c\lambda =0\\
L_{\lambda}=5-a^2-2b^2-c^2=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow \\
(a,b,c)=\left(0,\pm \sqrt{\frac 52},0\right) \Rightarrow d^2=\frac 52 \Rightarrow d=\sqrt{\frac 52} \ \text{(min)}\\
$$

Comment: I don't know about Lagrange thing. I'll look it up. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.